# Why does this angularjs directive not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am stuck trying to follow a tutorial on AngularJS directives.  I've been unable to find any syntax errors in the code, and I've even tried adding jQuery.

`main.js`

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive = ("enter", function () {
    return function (scope, element) {
        element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
            console.log("I'm inside of you!");
        });
    }
});
```

`ng.php`

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div enter>I'm content!</div>
</body>
```

Both AngularJS and main.js are linked correctly.

There are no console errors reported.

What am I missing?

Comment: Remove `=` (and spaces) after `app.directive` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.directive` is a function, not a property.

Where you have:

```
app.directive = ('enter'...
```

Should be:

```
app.directive('enter', function() ...)
```

So you are calling the function to register a directive, instead of overriding with an assignment so you can never have any directives ever again. :)